# Preventing an infinite loop with two $watches

Tags: angularjs, watch

I'm looking for a technique to prevent an infinite loop when using two `$watch` statements in angular.  The idea is when `var1` changes, I want it to modify `var2`.  When `var2` changes, I want it to modify `var1`.  But that will normally create an infinite loop.  Is there a way around this?    Below is a trivial example that demonstrates the issue.  This code would go in an angular controller.

```
$scope.$watch('var1', function(newVal){
    $scope.var2 = newVal
})
$scope.$watch('var2', function(newVal){
    $scope.var1 = newVal
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually wouldn't cause an infinite loop since the watch would stop being fired once both vars are equal.

1. Var 1 is modified by user
2. Var 1 watch fires and sets var2 = var1;
3. Var 2 watch fires and sets var1 = var2;
4. Since var 1's didn't actually change, the watch is no longer fired, no infinite loop happens.

Here's a snippet demonstrating this:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {

    $scope.$watch('var1', function(newVal) {
      $scope.var2 = newVal;
    });

    $scope.$watch('var2', function(newVal) {
      $scope.var1 = newVal;
    });

  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.17" data-semver="1.3.17" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/angular.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <label>Var1</label>
    <input ng-model="var1">
    <br/>
    <label>Var2</label>
    <input ng-model="var2">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ah yes, but that is just a trivial example where the one value is set directly to another value.  My situation is more complicated.  But I also discovered my issue was caused by bad design, and with a better structure I avoided needing mutual watches.  I feel like I should just close the question.

Comment: Actually I just went ahead an accepted your answer since I learned something new.  I didn't know that setting it to the same value would **not** trigger the `$watch`.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help.

Comment: Is this still true if the value is an array? I wanted to do something where I had an angular directive (ng-tags-input) that required a data model of an array of objects with a property called 'text', but I want to ultimately just save the data as an array of strings. But sometimes the array of strings would be updated and would need to update the tag-it control. I'm pretty sure I ended up with an infinite loop and the watch would fire even when newValue == oldValue, since the object references would still be different.